# Uniqueness of Perfect group of a given order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there only one perfect group (up to isomorphism) of a given order?

My intuitive thought is that a perfect group has such stringent requirements on the group product that it must be unique.

I do know that since each element of a perfect group is a commutator, then any homomorphism between the groups will be surjective. This is using the property that for any homomorphism $f:\mathbb G \to \mathbb H, \, f([h,g]) = [f(h),f(g)]$. However, I seem to be stuck on proving that a homomorphism between two perfect groups of equal order must exist.

Is there a counter-example? If my current thinking is correct, a hint on the rest of the proof would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false. Notice that all simple groups are perfect, and with that in mind notice that there are [pairs of finite simple groups of the same order.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34424/number-of-finite-simple-groups-of-given-order-is-at-most-2-is-a-classification)

Comment: srry I don't know abstract algebra. Wikipedia says all non-abelian simple groups are perfect. Is this also true for abelian simple groups?

Comment: @user4140 no. The commutator of every abelian group is the identity.

Comment: so then not all simple groups are perfect? your answer says all are, is that a typo or am I confused?

Comment: Are you aware of any examples that have more than a pair for any order? Thanks for the relevant link by the way.

Comment: @user4140 I should have said "finite simple non-cyclic groups".

Comment: @Clem no, I am not, but I am guessing that one can cook something up.

Comment: $$PSL_3(\Bbb F_4)\;,\;\;PSL_4(\Bbb F_2)$$ are two simple non-abelian non-isomorphic groups of order $\;20160\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio this is actually part of the content of my answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually very false indeed! The number ${\rm perf}(n)$ of isomorphism types of finite perfect groups of order at most $n$ satisfies:

$n^{l(n)^2/108−cl(n)} \le {\rm perf}(n) \le n^{l(n)^2/48+l(n)}$,

where $l(n)= \log_2(n)$ and $c=11/36$. For example, there are very large numbers of perfect groups of order $2^k.60$ for large $k$.

The reference is Holt, D. F.,
Enumerating perfect groups.
J. London Math. Soc. (2) 39 (1989), no. 1, 67–78

Comment: Do you have a reference for the bounds?

Comment: Cool! Are both bounds supposed supposed to be sharp, or is one of them, or?!

Comment: I've added the reference, which is to one of my own old papers. I would guess that the lower bound is the more accurate, but I have no idea how to prove it. (They can't both be sharp, can they?)